# How to creating an instance of a class and assign it to a variable?

Tags: gdb

For C++ code when debugging using gdb:
1) How to create a variable in gdb? Using gdb/mi command?
2) How to create a instance of a class in gdb.
3) How to assign the created instance to the created variable in gdb to make use in the future?
For example:

```
C++ code:
class C { public:int value; }

gdb commands (pseudo-code):
var v = new C()
print v.value
```

Comment: No, this is not my home work. It's for my works. I wanted to create a instance of logger class when the GDB breaks at the breakpoints, then I can inspect a complex instance of working class. The working class has many member variables and its members may have many members. So I need create the instance of the logger class to print out the information that I need.

Answer (score 2):

"new" is not currently supported in gdb.  It isn't handled in the parser at all.  There is a bug open for this in gdb bugzilla if you want to track progress on it.  Someone (cough cough) is working on it.

Meanwhile, I think maybe you can do it manually.  I have never tried this for real though.  The idea is something like:

```
set var $new = malloc(sizeof(struct Whatever))
call Whatever::Whatever($var)
```

However, you may need additional arguments in that call, since the C++ ABI specifies some magical hidden arguments.

Another approach is to make a debugging convenience function in your program:

```
whatever *new_w() { return new whatever(); }
```

Then you can just call this directly from gdb.